# iOS:- Error: Failed to create storage directory.Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, upgrade, asyncstorage

**Facing problem only in iOS, not in android.**

Failed to create storage directory.Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The file “%40amdig%2Fcenflex-puraskar” couldn’t be saved in the folder “ExponentExperienceData”." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B8974F4F-B2F1-432C-AEEA-29C3127761C5/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/%40amdig%2Fcenflex-puraskar, NSUnderlyingError=0x281ea1dd0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=20 "Not a directory"}}

**Version** : @react-native-async-storage/async-storage tried with these versions 1.15.9 , 1.15.5, 1.13.2

**System Information**
System:
OS: Windows 10 10.0.19043
CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8365U CPU @ 1.60GHz
Memory: 1.09 GB / 7.74 GB
Binaries:
Node: 14.17.4 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
Yarn: Not Found
npm: 6.14.14 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
Watchman: Not Found
SDKs:
Android SDK: Not Found
Windows SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: Not Found
Visual Studio: Not Found
Languages:
Java: Not Found
npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
react-native: 0.64.2 => 0.64.2
react-native-windows: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
*react-native*: Not Found

**Steps to Reproduce**

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

useEffect(async () => {
try {
console.log('test started')
await AsyncStorage.setItem("testKey", 'testValue');
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e, 'setItem test error ')
}
}, [])
```

**"bundleIdentifier": "com.domain.Cenflex",**

Earlier with same configuration there was no issue. After updating async-storage lib and expo I'm facing this error

Comment: I tried with many things but when I reinstalled the Expo Go app in iPhone and bug isn't there.

Comment: I am facing this exact issue after doing the exact changes. I upgraded my expo from SDK 42 to 43 and the `AsyncStorage` from `react-native` got deprecated so as the official docs suggest, I switched from this old usage to new plugin usage i.e. `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage` and started facing this issue.

Comment: Also for some reason, the first set of `setItem` and `getItem` calls work just fine but the next set of subsequent calls fail to throw the same exact error mentioned in the question. @Ahmed, have you found any resolution to this issue yet?

Answer (score 3):

I tried with many things but when I reinstalled the Expo Go app in iPhone and bug isn't there.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! This response doesn’t really answer the question and would be better as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when running the app on an iPhone simulator.

On my side the issue was with @react-native-async-storage/async-storage.

**How I solved the problem**

I deleted the Expo app on the simulator and re-installed it.